# Serializing rx-java Observable over the network

Tags: scala, akka, rx-java

I'm trying to serialize a subscription to send over the network. I'm using Scala, and doing something like this:

```scala
observable.materialize.subscribe{ n : Notification => sendToNetwork(n)}
```

However, I'm getting errors:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: rx.lang.scala.Notification$OnNext
```

(To be precise, I'm using Akka and trying to send the notifications to a remote actor. But I think this problem is more general than that).

It appears that it refuses to serialize the `OnNext` class, which is in fact a subclass of `Notification`, which is an inner class of the `rx.lang.scala.Notification` companion object:

http://rxscala.github.io/scaladoc/#rx.lang.scala.Notification$$OnNext

... and I think I saw somewhere in the java documentation that one can't serialize inner non-static classes.

Is my understanding of this correct? If so, is this a limitation of the class hierarchy of rx-java? Or is there some way to work around this, and serialize `Notification`s?

Answer (score 3):

> Is my understanding of this correct?

You *can* serialize non-static inner classes, provided the outer class is serializable. But both in Java and Scala you need to explicitly tell the compiler the class is serializable (by extending `Serializable`), and neither rx-java [`Notification`](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/blob/master/rxjava-core/src/main/java/rx/Notification.java) nor rx-scala `OnNext` are serializable.

> Or is there some way to work around this, and serialize Notifications?

In Akka, you can write your own serializers for any class: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/serialization.html. Java serialization is only used by default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I'm aware of the Akka custom serialization, and that's indeed what I ended up doing. Maybe I should have worded the question differently: *Why* does Notification not implement Serializable? It would seem a natural thing to do. Any idea? p.s. I've raised a request on github for this: https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/issues/1078 . Curious to see what they'll say.

Comment: Implementing Serializable is unfortunately the easy thing to do, but it is in most cases the wrong thing. We (Akka) also made the mistake of supporting Java Serialization, but we might in the future remove the default binding in order to make people aware that using that will yield sub-par performance in all respects and a brittle system between different language and runtime versions.

Answer (score 1):

Kontraktor-Reactive-Streams provides kick-ass remoting performance based on reactive streams.
You are not sucked into using Kontraktor but can use it as a tool to provide fast remoting (based on fast-serialization).

```
public static void remotingRxToRx() {
    Observable<Integer> range = Observable.range(0, 50_000_000);
    Publisher<Integer> pub = RxReactiveStreams.toPublisher(range);

    KxReactiveStreams.get().asRxPublisher(pub)
        .serve(new TCPNIOPublisher().port(3456));

    RateMeasure rm = new RateMeasure("events");

    KxPublisher<Integer> remoteStream =
        KxReactiveStreams.get()
            .connect(Integer.class, new TCPConnectable().host("localhost").port(3456));

    RxReactiveStreams.toObservable(remoteStream)
        .forEach( i -> rm.count() );
}
```

current link:
https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/kontraktor/tree/trunk/modules/reactive-streams/src/examples/src/rxstreamserver

will be moved into a separate project soon (just check my projects)